# How many times per rest cycle can a cleric cast their domain spells? And at what level are they cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, domains

The description for Domain Spells is vague.  Once a cleric gains access to a domain, can they cast the domain spells as often as they wish (like a cantrip) or only a certain number of times per rest cycle?

Also, at what level are these spells cast as some of them have greater effects as they are cast at higher level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting domain spells is still limited by the numbers and levels of spells you can cast per long rest.

Here's what the PHB says about cleric domain spells:

> Once you gain a domain spell, you always have it prepared, and it doesn't count against the number of spells you can prepare each day.

So the spell is always prepared. It counts as one of your prepared spells. Casting the spell will consume one of your per-long-rest spell slots of the appropriate level, and your spellcasting slots are limited.

The question of whether or not you can actually cast the spell, that depends on how many spell slots you have remaining, and the levels of those spell slots.

If you use a higher-level slot to cast a spell (i.e. higher than its normal slot) then it will consume a slot of the level you used. For example, if you get *Cure Wounds* as a domain spell, and you use a 4th level slot to cast it, then that uses up one of your 4th level spell slots.

Answer (score 7):

**Domain spells still consume spell slots.**

---

**Can they cast the domain spells as often as they wish (like a cantrip) or only a certain number of times per rest cycle?**

> Once you gain a domain spell, you always have it prepared, and it doesn't count against the number of Spells you can prepare each day.

Domain spells are simply spells that you don't have to think about preparing, they are always prepared. They still require spell slots and components if required in the spell description.

If a feature is intended to make a spell castable "at will", it will be clearly stated in the description, such as for the Warlock Invocation *Mask of Many Faces.*

> **Mask of Many Faces**: You can cast Disguise Self at will, without expending a spell slot.

---

**At what level are these spells cast as some of them have greater effects as they are cast at higher level?**

The level of the spell is chosen by the Cleric at the time of casting, the same as every other Cleric spell.